# Analyze sheet data to create a summary of values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet for employee schedule (you can see a demo in the link below). As you can see in the "original table", I have 2 rows per day and columns for every shift (Shift A, Shift B ... ).

[DEMO SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z8ayTVFA6BSLpV2sEMiTYjBp_Huo0KBeG6sMn6BjBfM/edit?usp=sharing)

I need to "reverse" the table, extracting every shift for any employee (as you can see in the right side of the demo table "calculated table").

I don't think it's possibile with normal formulas, I tried with `JOIN` formula and some `IF`s but it's not a working solution in my opinion.

Any idea on how can I write a custom formula in Google App Script? Do you know any workaround with formulas? Can you tell me where can I found some examples?

Notice that, sometimes, employee can have two shift in a single day.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to write a script to do this in Google Apps Script. No, we won't just do this for you. Yes, we will help you resolve any errors you get in the function you write to do this. Reviewing the Google Apps Script documentation for the Spreadsheet Service, and learning a bit of Javascript (Apps Script is Javascript v1.6 + some of Google's classes & APIs) should get you started

Comment: Consider researching Pivot tables and the `QUERY` formula as well. You can probably achieve your goal - printing the shifts for each worker on a given day - without Apps Script.

Comment: @tehhowch I'm not looking for someone that do the work for me. I know javascript and how to write in GAS. I'm looking for some idea or workaround because I'm in trouble with my question. I will try with pivot and query (I'm starting to read documentation right now). Any example to suggest? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

J7:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(" ; ";1;IF(OFFSET($A$5;MATCH($I7;$A$6:$A$25;0);2;2;3)=J$6;$C$5:$E$5;)))
```

DragFill down and out.

- OFFSET to offset the date to 2x3 Data array for the MATCHed date
- IF to get Header Rows
- TEXTJOIN to Join results.